# FedACHdir.txt download

Tags: http, download

We had an automated process to download FedACHDir.txt at href="https://www.frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/FedACHdir.txt.

This download page now has a pop-up form appearing to inform the availability of the data in 2018 and to input information to get notified.

The download process we had was working so far (until couple of weeks back) and is not working now after this pop-up form starts appearing.

Does anyone face similar issues and any ideas/suggestion on how to overcome this?

i tried with few options like the curl script below (and wget and also java process):
curl  -s -c fcookie.txt https://www.frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/FedACHdir.txt
curl -b fcookie.txt -d "agreementValue=Agree" -H "Referer:https://www.frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/agreement.html" https://www.frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/submitAgreement
curl -b fcookie.txt "https://www.frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/FedACHdir.txt"  -o ./FedACHdir.txt

thanks,

Comment: Would you mind formatting the three `curl` commands you've included, and perhaps showing the output you are getting for each? Perhaps separating them with a blank line would also help. Many thanks!

Comment: Here is the latest curl commands i tried:
1.
curl --cookies-jar cookies.txt "https://www.frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/agreement.html" 


2.
curl --cookie cookies.txt --cookies-jar cookies.txt "https://www.frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/submitAgreement" --referer: https://www.frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/agreement.html" --data "agreementValue=Agree" 


3.
curl --cookie cookies.txt --cookies-jar cookies.txt "https://frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/FedACHdir.txt" 

Files created are:
cookies.txt &
FedACHdir.txt - this file is 0 bytes


Thanks for checking.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE (1/18/2020): The Fed is no longer allowing external access to this data at all. The following no longer works:**

Had to figure this out for work because we needed to verify bank routing numbers...automating the update of this list was required.

Here is my research, and solution(s) to the task.

First of all, the `FedACHdir.txt` file is behind a form requiring you to agree to the terms of use (I suggest anyone doing this to first make sure they are not violating these terms before implementing this automated solution: https://www.frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/agreement.html).

These are the steps you must follow (in general) to download the `FedACHdir.txt` file (as of this writing, **April 11, 2018**):

1. The initial form at `https://www.frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/submitAgreement` must be `POST`'d to with the `agreementValue` set to `Agree`. This results in the creation of a session cookie: `JSESSIONID`.
2. Then the cookie property `abaDataCaptureCookie` must be manually set to the value: `abaDataCaptureCookie`
3. Using the initialized session and manually set cookie, we can now `GET` the `FedACHdir.txt` file at `https://www.frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/FedACHdir.txt`

In short, here are two solutions:

- **Wget**

  ```
  # Step 1 - Setup Session
  wget frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/submitAgreement \
    --post-data="agreementValue=Agree" \
    --save-cookies cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --delete-after

  # Step 2 - Set Cookie
  echo -e "frbservices.org\tFALSE\t/EPaymentsDirectory/\tFALSE\t0\t" \
    "abaDataCaptureCookie\tabaDataCaptureCookie" >>cookies.txt

  # Step 3 - Download FedACHdir.txt
  wget --load-cookies cookies.txt frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/FedACHdir.txt
  ```
- **PHP Guzzle 6 (what I used)**

  ```
  $frbDomain = "www.frbservices.org";
  $frbDir = "https://{$frbDomain}/EPaymentsDirectory";

  $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;
  $jar = new \GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar;

  // Step 1 - Setup Session
  $client->request('POST', "{$frbDir}/submitAgreement", [
    'cookies' => $jar,
    'form_params' => [ 'agreementValue' => 'Agree' ],
  ]);

  // Step 2 - Set Cookie
  $jar->setCookie(new \GuzzleHttp\Cookie\SetCookie([
    'Name' => 'abaDataCaptureCookie',
    'Value' => 'abaDataCaptureCookie',
    'Domain' => $frbDomain,
  ]));

  // Step 3 - Download FedACHdir.txt
  $fedACHDir = $client->request('GET', "{$frbDir}/FedACHdir.txt", [
    'cookies' => $jar
  ])->getBody()->getContents();
  ```

Hope this helps someone searching for a solution to this.

Comment: I haven't tried the php version but wget solution doesn't seem to work as of today 4.23.2018. FedACHdir.txt contains html code instead.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like www.frbservices.org changed their spec.  If you're accessing a tool that isn't documented as for public consumption, that can happen, and when it does you need to handle the new form.  frbservices, may have thought this through already.

If you want to write a script without contacting them, you need to know what the flow is supposed to be (were it being accessed the way they expect it, such as via a browser).

If you wget the url, what do you get?  Normally popups are javascript, and you can ignore them.  Alternatively the page may now only be the popup, and it may be javascript that is directing you elsewhere to get the file.   Basically you need a web developer to code this, hence best ask frbservices how best you should download this file.

Comment: Thanks for your comments!
i believe this is for public consumption.

here is the wget command sequence i am trying:
1. 
wget  https://www.frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/agreement.html --save-cookies cookie.txt --keep-session-cookies 

2.
wget --load-cookies=cookie.txt --post-data="agreementValue=Agree" https://frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/submitAgreement --save-cookies cookie.txt --keep-session-cookies 
3.
wget --load-cookies=cookie.txt https://frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/FedACHdir.txt

FedACHdir.txt directory seems to contain the agreement page downloaded

Comment: That's not exactly what I mean.  If you use a browser to work through the UI sequence, and keep tabs of the network activity on the tab, specifically on the last step of that, you need to see exactly what the request for the .txt file returns.  Is it the file itself, or a 302, or is it a page with js in it, that directs the browser to popup your notice.  Its how that last page returns, that's important

Comment: It's the HTTP conversation,at that last stage that you need to look at.  It'll be GET /EPayments...dir.txt and the response will be 200 with data or 304 with a redirct url.  If it's a page of data, what does that contain?  Where does the popup content come from?  What exact request (when you do it in a browser) results in your .txt page

Comment: you may need to inspect the network log, to answer that final question, but that's what you need to script to rerun.